# How to communicate between containers in a multi-container Heroku app

Tags: docker, heroku

I am trying to roll out a small test app to Heroku that includes a front end client (an Angular app) and an API server (written in .Net Core). I am using Docker images to do this. According to the [documentation for containers on Heroku,](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#pushing-multiple-images) you are able to push multiple containers to a single Heroku app. I have successfully set it up so the webapp is displayed when you navigate to the URL, but I can't seem to find a way to communicate with the server. Is there a specific URL that links to a specific container? If not, then what kinds of systems can you build with multi-container apps on Heroku?

The documentation does not seem to clarify this. The only answer I could possibly come up with for this is to use one container to receive and answer incoming HTTP requests, while the other containers act as workers for background tasks (although the documentation doesn't seem to detail how the two types of containers would communicate in this case).

Comment: realted : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49999920/docker-compose-heroku-hostmane-links-and-production-deployment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker compose, heroku, hostmane links and production deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49999920/docker-compose-heroku-hostmane-links-and-production-deployment)