# How to deploy multi-container app to Heroku?

Tags: docker, heroku, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yml`. It has multiple services which talk to each other.

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  model:
    build:
      context: ./services/model
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    container_name: model
    volumes:
      - ./services/model/:/usr/app

  server:
    build:
      context: ./services/server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    container_name: server
    env_file: ./services/server/.env
    depends_on:
      - db
      - model
    volumes:
      - ./services/server/:/usr/app
      - node_modules:/usr/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "${SERVER_PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}"

volumes:
  dbdata:
  node_modules:
```

I want to deploy the same to Heroku. I found [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml) about how to deploy multi-container apps to Heroku using `heroku.yml`. But there does not seem to be any explanation about how to create a network between these containers and let them talk to one another.

I would like to know how to  accomplish the same using Heroku.

Thank you !

***EDITED***:

I have removed `db` service because heroku's `postgres` addon could be used. Also, neglect the volume mounting part. It was just for local development.

But, I need `server` to comminucate with `model` service. So, I need them to be on the same network like in `docker-compose` which creates a virtual network for containers to talk to each other. I also saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50000234/10837538) which says Docker swarm could be used. But I found out that it is no longer actively maintained. Kubernetes could also be an option but I need some way to deploy this kind of app on Heroku. I am a newbie to Docker. So any advice is going to be hugely appreciated !

Thanks !

Comment: I don't see anything about multi-container apps in that article. It does talk about multi-stage builds, but that's different. You cannot run your own arbitrary services on Heroku, especially data stores like Postgres. Use an [appropriate addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores) or other hosted service. Note that  there is no way to mount persistent volumes on Heroku, either. As far as I know there is no way to configure a network for your containers.

Comment: Thanks  @Chris for answering. I have updated the question. Could you please have another look at it ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to set up inter-container communication on Heroku. That's not what it's designed to do. You might want to look at other hosting options.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I have to look at Kubernetes