# How to make Nginx in a web dyno to find a node app in a worker dyno?

Tags: docker, nginx, heroku, devops, gitlab-ci

I am trying to deploy an Angular Application in Heroku with Nginx as reverse proxy (two containers/dynos).

The web container (Nginx) crashes as it can’t find the worker container (Node/Express with SSR):

BTW I'm also using dockerfiles and Gitlab CI/CD for the pipeline.

I'm getting the following error:

```
2021-12-17T18:23:30.617790+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-12-17T18:23:30.696851+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-12-17T18:23:30.704189+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-12-17T18:23:30.486129+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021/12/17 18:23:30 [emerg] 3#3: host not found in upstream "worker" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:9
2021-12-17T18:23:30.486148+00:00 app[web.1]: nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "worker" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:9
```

My configuration is:

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```yaml
build:
  image: trion/ng-cli:11.2.12
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm audit fix
    - npm run-script build:ssr
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist
  only:
    refs:
      - tags
      - master

deploy:
  image: docker:20.10.7
  stage: deploy
  services:
    - docker:20.10.7-dind
  before_script:
    # Install Heroku CLI
    - apk update
    - apk add bash
    - apk add curl
    - apk add --update nodejs npm
    - curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh | sh
    - export HEROKU_API_KEY=$HEROKU_API_KEY
  script:
    - heroku container:login
    - heroku container:push --recursive --app=$HEROKU_APP_PRODUCTION
    - heroku container:release web worker --app=$HEROKU_APP_PRODUCTION
  dependencies:
    - build
  only:
    refs:
      - tags
      - master
```

**Dockerfile.worker**

```yaml
FROM node:14-alpine3.12
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/dist/usermetrics/browser
COPY dist/usermetrics/browser/index.html /usr/src/app/dist/usermetrics/browser/index.html
COPY dist/usermetrics/server /usr/src/app
EXPOSE $PORT
CMD node main.js
```

**Dockerfile.web**

```yaml
FROM nginx:1.17.8-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY dist/usermetrics/browser .
```

**nginx.conf**

```
worker_processes  auto;

events {
    worker_connections  8192;
}

http {
    upstream nodeserver_upstream {
        server worker; <---- here!
    }
    server {
        listen ${PORT};
        server_name  localhost;

        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        # compression
        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        # # angular index.html location
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
        # # potential reverse proxy for sending api calls
        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header Content-Type application/json;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://nodeserver_upstream/;
        }

        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

}
```

Pipeline finishes without any errors and I can see both dynos: web and worker up, but with that error in the log.

[image]

Am I missing something? how to properly set nginx.conf to redirect the traffic to the Express server in the other dyno?

Answer (score 0):

By default, dynos are isolated and cannot reach each other. Additionally, worker dynos are not intended to be reachable directly by other dynos. Only web dynos can receive traffic from routers.

To route between your dynos like this, you would need to use [private spaces](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/private-spaces) and separate apps.

See [Networking documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#networking) and [Runtime documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-runtime#private-spaces-runtime) for more information on networking between your dynos.

If you want to support an interface which is similar to `docker-compose` or Docker Swarm, where each container is automatically networked together, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50000234/5747944) which explains a workaround.